# Installing .NET Framework package to PCL attempts to install .NET Standard packages

Tags: nuget, .net-core, system.reactive, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I have a portable class library project targeting `.NET Framework 4.5`, and am trying to install `System.Reactive.Interfaces` to this project.

The dependencies for `System.Reactive.Interfaces` are `NETStandard.Library` for a `.NETStandard project`, but no dependencies for a `.NET Framework` project. Therefore this project should install `Reactive.Interfaces` without needing to install any other packages. My project also has a `packages.config` file, and no `project.json` or `project.lock.json` files exist in the solution.

However, attempting to install `Reactive.Interfaces` prompts me to install all of the `System.*` packages needed for `.NET Core`, as well as `NETStandard.Library 1.6.0`. How can I convince Nuget that this is a PCL for `.NET Framework 4.5` instead of a `.NET Standard` project?

Comment: If you do want to target .NET Framework, don't create a PCL. Please create a classic class library project.

Answer (score -2):

.Net Standrd is like "new" PCL but more complex. Change PCL to .Net Standard Library (if you want still use .Net Framework 4.5 you need to use .NET Standard 1.1). For more information i recommend this [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md)